# PHP counting JSON elements with specific property

Tags: php, json, count

I have a json like this:

```
{
"data": [
{
"prop1":"aaa",
"prop2":"bbb",
"prop3":"1234",
"prop4":"2006"
},
{
"prop1":"ccc",
"prop2":"ddd",
"prop3":"4567",
"prop4":"2016"
},
{
"prop1":"aaa",
"prop2":"ddd",
"prop3":"4567",
"prop4":"2002"
}
]}
```

It will have ~100 elements and I need to count elements with specified property, I tried something with

```
echo count($json['data']);
```

but it will get me count of all elements of json - I need to know the number of elements with `prop1 => "aaa"`

what I have so far:

```
$file = "test.json";

$fh = fopen($file, 'a') or die();
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents($file), true);



echo '<pre>';
print_r($json);
exit();

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to create a callback filter function

```
<?php 


$json = '{
"data": [
{
"prop1":"aaa",
"prop2":"bbb",
"prop3":"1234",
"prop4":"2006"
},
{
"prop1":"ccc",
"prop2":"ddd",
"prop3":"4567",
"prop4":"2016"
},
{
"prop1":"aaa",
"prop2":"ddd",
"prop3":"4567",
"prop4":"2002"
}
]}';



echo '<pre>';
$data = json_decode($json);
print_r($data->data);
$data->data = array_filter($data->data, function($item) { 
    return $item->prop1 == 'aaa';
});
print_r($data->data);
exit();

?>
```